# "npm install expo-cli --global" doesnt working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I'm trying to install expo-cli but for some reason ı'm getting this error.

```
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":{"caniuse-db":"^1.0'
```

I also try 
npm install expo-cli -g --unsafe-perm

npm install expo-cli -g --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

but this are not working too. How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: this works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/60699739/4539729

Answer (score 0):

open the terminal as `admin` or `sudo`.

check the registry of npm, it should be `https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Npm uses Cache for downloading new packages for you. You need to clear your npm cache. use following command to clean, and install it :

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g expo-cli
```

its work for me.