# expo version command shows running scripts disabled on this machine

Tags: windows, powershell, react-native, terminal, windows-10

I am trying to develop a react native project in my Windows 10 machine. I installed node js then expo cli via visual studio code terminal. Then I tried the command `expo --version`, the terminal shows error::

```
expo : File C:\Users\saka\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more 
information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ expo --version
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

the given link shows many things, but what shall I do to solve my problem? 
Thank You!!!

Comment: Problem solved via the link :: `https://techpasser.com/react-native/expo-error-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just try to open Windows PowerShell run as administrator and then run this command line:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Answer (score 21):

Step1 : start power shell in administrator mode.

Step2 : Type the following command "set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned"

Step3: Press Y for your Confirmation.

Answer (score 10):

Paste this code in your terminal

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Press Enter

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

Trying to run expo start command via the integrated terminal of visual studio IDE which is by **default not authorized**.

In such case you open the CMD and **run it as an administrator** and then type `expo start` in the project directory. This will work.

For more information please [visit this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/user-permissions-and-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: You need to open your power shell or command line with ‘Run as Administrator’ by right-clicking on its icon.

Step 2: You need to type in the following command:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

[refer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLIEX.png)

Step 3: You will see the following message and permission request. Type ‘a’ and enter

[refer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egrgl.png)

Solution 2:

Try running the following command in PowerShell after running as administrator.

> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted

Now go and tried installing and then running ‘Expo’

Comment: `Unrestricted` should not be used on any system where it is possible to download a script.  `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned `, should be the minimum security setting.  This allows locally created scripts to be run, but will protect against malicious scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:

Trying to run expo start command via the integrated terminal of visual studio IDE which is by default not authorized.

In such a case, you open the CMD and run it as an **administrator mode** and then type **expo --version** in the project directory. This will work.

Solution 2:

Try running the following command in PowerShell after running as **administrator mode**.

**Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted**
type **A** Yes to All

Now go and tried installing and then running ‘Expo’

Comment: `Unrestricted` should not be used on any system where it is possible to download a script.  `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned `, should be the minimum security setting.  This allows locally created scripts to be run, but will protect against malicious scripts.

Answer (score 2):

In case You are using Command Prompt follow this:

1. Open **CMD and Run it as Administrator**

2: **Run this command:** powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted

3. run: expo & **you have all set**

Answer (score 1):

How to set PowerShell script execution policy within Visual Studio Code:

Open Settings, and click/tap on the Update & security icon. 2. Click/tap on For developers on the left side, check the Change execution policy to allow local PowerShell scripts to run without signing. Require signing for remote scripts. box under PowerShell on the right side, and click/tap on the Apply button.

do this thing your problem must be solve if u r windows 10 user

Answer (score 1):

. Open Settings, and click/tap on the Update & security icon. 2. Click/tap on For developers on the left side, check the Change execution policy to allow local PowerShell scripts to run without signing. Require signing for remote scripts. box under PowerShell on the right side, and click/tap on the Apply button.

do this thing your problem must be solve if u r windows 10 user

100% Working

Answer (score 1):

Just open cmd on Windows (not Visual Code Terminal), works fine for me. If you are in cmd, run `expo --version` and see if you still get any errors.

It's not a secure way to deactivate this setting, based on what Microsoft says: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while using Expo commands on Windows PowerShell but ran the same command on Windows cmd without error.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred while I was working in the VSCode terminal and the default option was PowerShell, I changed it to the cmd and it appears to be fixed. In my opinion, this is a much better fix than allowing any script to be executed by PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `Unrestricted` should not be used on any system where it is possible to download a script.  `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned `, should be the minimum security setting.  This allows locally created scripts to be run, but will protect against malicious scripts.